# convert an sql query to laravel eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have this SQL RAW query:

```
select * from table_a where (select id from table_b where table_a.table_b_id = table_b.id and table_b.code = '02') = table_a.table_b_id  and user = '123456'  order by id desc limit 1
```

I need convert to Laravel eloquent.  i have been trying for hours

Comment: Check this. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries

Answer (score 0):

this apparently worked

```
$tran = Table_A::join('table_b', function ($join) {
    $join->on('table_a.table_b_id', '=', 'table_b.id')
        ->where('table_b.code', '02');
})->where('user', '123456')
   ->orderBy('table_a.id', "DESC")->limit(1)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Terminology correction: this is not [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent), which uses Laravel models, but [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries).

Answer (score 0):

If you want use Eloquent you must create models and relationships. Figure out, how these two table connected: hasOne, hasMany, hasManyThrough etc. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

When you create models and their relationships your query will be Eloquent.